# Why does Julia throw a bound error when deleting an element from priority queue

Tags: julia, queue

I am learning Julia and have encountered a frustrating error. Consider the following function:

```
function deletetag(id::Id, tag::Tag, dat::DataSet)
  if haskey(dat.tags, id)
    tags = dat.tags[id]
    if haskey(tags, tag)
      dat.tags[id] = delete!(tags, tag)
    end
  end
  nothing
end
```

the parameter dat contains some priority queues in its .tags field, the particular queue is found using the id passed as first parameter. I want to remove the given tag from the priority queue, but the delete! method throws the following error:

```
BoundsError: attempt to access 19-element Vector{Pair{Main.Ana.Tag, Main.Ana.Tag}} at index [22]

Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex
   @ ./array.jl:924 [inlined]
 [2] force_up!(pq::DataStructures.PriorityQueue{Main.Ana.Tag, Main.Ana.Tag, Main.Ana.TagOrder}, i::Int64)
   @ DataStructures ~/.julia/packages/DataStructures/59MD0/src/priorityqueue.jl:163
 [3] dequeue_pair!
   @ ~/.julia/packages/DataStructures/59MD0/src/priorityqueue.jl:324 [inlined]
 [4] delete!(pq::DataStructures.PriorityQueue{Main.Ana.Tag, Main.Ana.Tag, Main.Ana.TagOrder}, key::Main.Ana.Tag)
   @ DataStructures ~/.julia/packages/DataStructures/59MD0/src/priorityqueue.jl:346
 [5] deletetag(id::Main.Ana.Frames.FrameId, tag::Main.Ana.Tag, dat::Main.Ana.DataSet)
   @ Main.Ana ~/Documents/school/Bachelor Thesis/Thesis/src/Ana.jl:162
 [6] filter(cs::Vector{Main.Ana.Frames.FrameId}, key::Main.Ana.Keys.Key, dat::Main.Ana.DataSet; choose::var"#81#83", window::Int64, beginning::Main.Ana.Keys.Key, ending::Main.Ana.Keys.Key)
   @ Main.Ana ~/Documents/school/Bachelor Thesis/Thesis/src/Ana.jl:400
 [7] top-level scope
   @ ~/Documents/school/Bachelor Thesis/Thesis/src/Schubert.ipynb:12
```

I cannot figure out what is happening here, my first thought is that there is a bug in Julia's code, the reason why I think so is that the inner implementation of the priority queue throws the error, which should not happen. On the other hand I might just be doing something that I am really not supposed to do, like calling the delete! method like that?

My question is: why do I get this bound error, if this is supposed to happen, how am I supposed to delete an element from a priority queue? Note that I did override the Base.:(==) and Base.hash(...) methods for type Tag.

Thank you.

Edit, definition of DataSet:

```
struct DataSet <: Hierarchy
  
  wrapped::Chakra.Hierarchy
  data::Dict{Id, Constituent}
  tags::Dict{Id, PriorityQueue{Tag, Tag}} # MAKE CHARM ATTRIBUTE
  
  function DataSet(wrapped::Chakra.Hierarchy)
    new(wrapped, Dict(), Dict())
  end

end
```

Constituent and Hierarchy are just abstract types:

```
abstract type Id end
abstract type Constituent end
abstract type Hierarchy end
```

The chackra module can be found here: https://github.com/nick-harley/Chakra/blob/main/src/Chakra.jl

Tags as followed:

```
struct Tag <: Constituent
  
  complete::Bool
  root::Int
  key::Key
  inversion::Int
  score::Float64

  function Tag(c, r, k, i, s)
    new(c, r, k, i, s)
  end
  function Tag()
    new(false, -1, Keys.major(-1), -1, 0)
  end
  function Tag(k)
    new(true, k.pitch, k, 0, -1)
  end

end
```

Comment: Most likely the problem is with your datatype `DataSet` - what is it?

Comment: I have edited the post, it should be visible now :)

Comment: Could you please add the exact definitions of `Chakra` and `Hierarchy` so that we can reproduce the same thing as you on our machines?

Comment: I would also recommend including `import Pkg; Pkg.add("DataStructures"); using DataStructures` for all external packages that you use.

Comment: Sure! I have edited the post with the additional information, I did use the Pkg module to install the datastructures :)

Comment: You'll also have to add the definitions of `Key`, `Keys` etc for people to reproduce this

Comment: Keys is just another module, and a Key is a struct like so: struct Key <: Constituent
  pitch
  majmin
end, where pitch is an integer and majmin an array of integers (length 7).